# Insert Element between two elements with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to add an extra Table between two tables in a pdf file.

[image: Add Element between]

Things to consider:

- The Blue and the Red one always have a fixed height.
- The Green table height between different file may change and after adding the Red element in the middle, we may need two pages.
- What I know? I know how to make a table and add it to a pdf file.

My Question: Is it possible to move the Green Element and add the Red one between? How?

Comment: Are there any restrictions where to break the green table if necessary?

Comment: @mkl There is no restriction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say that you *know how to make a table and add it to a pdf file* and that *the Blue and the Red one always have a fixed height*, let's assume

- you have already created the table for the red part in a separate PDF,
- you have determined the *y* coordinate at which to split the input document to insert the red part, and
- you also have determined between which *y* coordinates in the separate PDF the table to insert is located.

Thus, the problem is reduced to

- "cutting" the input document page into three stripes,

  - the stripe above the splitting *y* coordinate containing the blue box,
  - the stripe below the splitting *y* coordinate containing as much of the green box as will still fit on that page after insertion of the red box, and
  - the stripe at the bottom of the page containing the remainder of the green box that will overflow to a new second page,
- "cutting" a stripe from the separate PDF containing the red box to insert, and
- "pasting" these stripes together in the desired new order.

For this you can use a tool like this:

```
public class CutAndPasteTool
{
    readonly Document document;
    readonly PdfWriter pdfWriter;
    readonly Dictionary<string, PdfTemplate> templates = new Dictionary<string, PdfTemplate>();

    public CutAndPasteTool(Rectangle pageSize, Stream os)
    {
        document = new Document(pageSize);
        pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, os);
        document.Open();
    }

    public ICutter CreateCutter(PdfReader pdfReader, int pageNumber)
    {
        return new SimpleCutter(pdfReader, pageNumber, pdfWriter, templates);
    }

    public void Paste(string name, float x, float y)
    {
        pdfWriter.DirectContent.AddTemplate(templates[name], x, y);
    }

    public void NewPage()
    {
        document.NewPage();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        document.Close();
    }

    class SimpleCutter : ICutter
    {
        readonly PdfImportedPage importedPage;
        readonly Dictionary<string, PdfTemplate> templates;

        internal SimpleCutter(PdfReader pdfReader, int pageNumber, PdfWriter pdfWriter, Dictionary<string, PdfTemplate> templates)
        {
            this.importedPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, pageNumber);
            this.templates = templates;
        }

        public void Cut(string name, Rectangle rectangle)
        {
            PdfTemplate template = importedPage.CreateTemplate(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
            template.AddTemplate(importedPage, importedPage.BoundingBox.Left - rectangle.Left, importedPage.BoundingBox.Bottom - rectangle.Bottom);
            templates.Add(name, template);
        }
    }
}

public interface ICutter
{
    void Cut(string name, Rectangle rectangle);
}
```

Using this tool you can cut the stripes and paste them like this:

```
Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4; // The page size of the result file
int doc1page = 1;                 // The number of the page in the input PDF
float doc1split = 600;            // The splitting y coordinate in the input PDF
int doc2page = 1;                 // The number of the page in the separate PDF
float doc2from = 700;             // The top y coordinate of the table in the separate PDF
float doc2to = 600;               // The bottom y coordinate of the table in the separate PDF

using (PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(...))           // The input PDF file
using (PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(...))           // The separate PDF file
using (Stream os = new FileStream(..., FileMode.Create)) // The stream to write the result to
{
    Rectangle doc1box = reader1.GetPageSize(doc1page);
    Rectangle doc1upper = new Rectangle(doc1box);
    doc1upper.Bottom = doc1split;
    Rectangle doc1lower = new Rectangle(doc1box);
    doc1lower.Top = doc1split;

    Rectangle doc2box = reader2.GetPageSize(doc2page);
    Rectangle doc2inset = new Rectangle(doc2box);
    doc2inset.Top = doc2from;
    doc2inset.Bottom = doc2to;

    float doc1lowerRemainHeight = pageSize.Height - doc1upper.Height - doc2inset.Height;
    float doc1lowerOverflowHeight = doc1lower.Height - doc1lowerRemainHeight;

    Rectangle doc1lowerRemain = new Rectangle(doc1lower);
    doc1lowerRemain.Bottom = doc1lowerRemain.Top - doc1lowerRemainHeight;
    Rectangle doc1lowerOverflow = new Rectangle(doc1lower);
    doc1lowerOverflow.Top = doc1lowerRemain.Bottom;

    CutAndPasteTool tool = new CutAndPasteTool(pageSize, os);

    ICutter cutterDoc1 = tool.CreateCutter(reader1, doc1page);
    cutterDoc1.Cut("Top1", doc1upper);
    cutterDoc1.Cut("Bottom1Remain", doc1lowerRemain);
    cutterDoc1.Cut("Bottom1Overflow", doc1lowerOverflow);
    ICutter cutterDoc2 = tool.CreateCutter(reader2, doc2page);
    cutterDoc2.Cut("Inset", doc2inset);

    float y = pageSize.Top;
    tool.Paste("Top1", 0, y-= doc1upper.Height);
    tool.Paste("Inset", 0, y -= doc2inset.Height);
    tool.Paste("Bottom1Remain", 0, y -= doc1lowerRemain.Height);

    tool.NewPage();

    y = pageSize.Top;
    tool.Paste("Bottom1Overflow", 0, y -= doc1lowerOverflow.Height);

    tool.Close();
}
```

**Beware:** This tool only works for content in the page content streams or content streams referenced from there, in particular not for content in annotations or XFA forms.

In case of annotations one can extend the solution to associate each annotation with one of those stripes (which might be difficult for border cases) and copy stripes and associated annotations together.

In case of XFA form tables this approach won't work unless you flatten the form first.

Furthermore, there now is some hidden text which nonetheless can be copied and pasted elsewhere. If that is not acceptable, one can replace the `SimpleCutter` by a more advanced `ICutter` implementation which removes (and not only hides) content outside of stripes, e.g. using the iText `PdfCleanUpProcessor`.