# Taking text from a PDF and inserting it into another PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a task that I have been fighting with. We have a PDF that has text inside it and I need to take that text and place it into another at the end of every page. The issue we are having is there are characters in PDF 1 that do not copy over as they are not recognized characters turning them into little boxes.

I have tried to turn the pdf into an image and insert it that way, I've tried to extract the text from the original pdf and insert it and could not find a way to do so without downloading a 3rd party library which I can't do, and I have started trying to just insert the pdf into the pdf.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want with iTextSharp or anything else built in? I cannot download any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: You might consider reusing some code from the `CutAndPasteTool` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48648519/1729265), you should merely improve it to "paste" onto an existing PDF (using a `PdfReader` / `PdfStamper` pair) instead of onto a blank new PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You best bet will be to insert the pages with text into the other PDF, you can use iText for that.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is a missing font issue. If you know the font that is causing the issue then you can try to [embed that font](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/81/itextsharp-working-with-fonts) in your target document.

If you have a little time on your hands then you might want to see if you can merge source and target fonts so you always have them there. However, the missing font has to be installed on the server where the merge is performed for this to succeed.